# Установка с помощью cmake

Tags: cmake, makefile

Как изменить мой cmake скрипт так, чтобы после команд cmake . && make && make install помимо того что бинарник скомпилируется, файл конфигурации должен скопироваться в /etc/myprog.cfg а бинарник скопироваться в /usr/bin? Если с помощь cmake нельзя сделать нечто подобное, подскажите подход для создания установщика.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
install(TARGETS <target> DESTINATION /usr/bin COMPONENT binaries)
install(FILES <config file> DESTINATION /etc COMPONENT config)
```

Разумеется, вместо угловых скобок нужно подставить актуальные значения.

Answer (score -1):

Зависит от конкретного дистрибутива.
А вообще есть [утилита](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=install&russian=2) "install", которая используется в `redhat` подобных дистрибутивах для копирования файлов из `RPM`.

Comment: Для 'копирования файлов из rpm' используется как правило сам `rpm` :) но не как не `install`